# Interpolation inequality on Holder space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, interpolation, holder-spaces

Let $0< \beta < \gamma <1$. Show that the interpolation inequality holds.

$$||U||_{C^{0,\gamma}(U)} \le ||U||^{\frac{1-\gamma}{1-\beta}}_{C^{0,\beta}(U)} ||U||^{\frac{\gamma-\beta}{1-\beta}}_{C^{0,1}(U)}.$$

Comment: This is not a juke-box. Have you tried anything? Any ideas or difficulties in applying the definition of the norms?

Comment: what I need is a clue because am having difficulty with applying the definition of the norms

Comment: Detailed proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099613/70305).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: express $\gamma$ as a convex combination of $\beta$ and $1$, say $\gamma=a+b\beta$ where $a+b=1$. Then notice that 
$$|x-y|^\gamma=|x-y|\cdot |x-y|^{b\beta}$$
and use the property $\sup_{z\in I}|g(z)h(z)|\leqslant \sup_{z\in I}|g(z)|\sup_{z\in I}|h(z)|$.

Comment: Davide, can you explain your hint?

Comment: @avati91w Which part of the hint is not clear to you?